# Regex to match the given formats

Tags: regex

i'm trying to match the below names

- abc.cdf.ghi.klm-1.0.0.zip
- abc.cdf.ghi.klm_config-1.0.0.18.zip

I have created `^abc.cdf.ghi.klm(-|_config)(\d*).(\d*).(\d*)(.(\d*).zip)`, but its only matching the first name. How to match the second name

Comment: You just missed - after config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern has multiple issues, including not being correct and also not escaping regex metacharacters.  Consider this version:

```regex
^abc\.cdf\.ghi\.klm(?:_config)?-\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.zip$
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```regex
^                   from the start of the filename
abc\.cdf\.ghi\.klm  match abc.cdf.ghi.klm
(?:_config)?        optionally followed by _config
-                   -
\d+                 a number
(?:\.\d+)*          optionally followed by dot/number zero or more times
\.zip               ending in .zip
$                   end of the filename
```